# Error during bosh deploy: "Arguments are not correct, details: 'expected string value for member 1 of key values of member 1 of option filters"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-foundry, bosh-deployer

I try to deploy [simple example](https://github.com/georgethebeatle/simple-bosh-release). I didn't change anything except **warden.yml** file. So, I tried to deploy it to AWS and use elastic IP, so I can access the server with specific IP.

When I deploy it I receive:

```
Director task 67
Deprecation: Ignoring cloud config. Manifest contains 'networks' section.

  Started preparing deployment > Preparing deployment. Done (00:00:00)

  Started preparing package compilation > Finding packages to compile. Done (00:00:00)

  Started creating missing vms > webapp/3a8acd3a-77a8-4bad-8de4-fb544d70f76d (0). Failed: Unknown CPI error 'InvalidCall' with message 'Arguments are not correct, details: 'expected string value for member 1 of key values of member 1 of option filters'' in 'create_vm' CPI method (00:00:05)

Error 100: Unknown CPI error 'InvalidCall' with message 'Arguments are not correct, details: 'expected string value for member 1 of key values of member 1 of option filters'' in 'create_vm' CPI method
```

What is the reason of this error?

**warden.yml**

```
name: webapp-warden
director_uuid: <%= `bosh status --uuid` %>

releases:
- name: simple-bosh-release
  version: latest

compilation:
  workers: 1
  network: webapp-network
  reuse_compilation_vms: true
  cloud_properties:
    instance_type: t2.medium
    availability_zone: us-west-2a

update:
  canaries: 1
  canary_watch_time: 30000-240000
  update_watch_time: 30000-600000
  max_in_flight: 3

resource_pools:
- name: common-resource-pool
  network: webapp-network
  size: 1
  stemcell:
    name: bosh-aws-xen-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent
    version: latest
  cloud_properties:
    instance_type: t2.medium
    availability_zone: us-west-2a

networks:
- name: webapp-network
  type: vip
  cloud_properties:
    security_groups:
    - default
  # cloud_properties:
    # subnet: subnet-87d256ce
- name: default
  type: dynamic
  cloud_properties:
    security_groups:
    - default

jobs:
- name: webapp
  template: webapp
  instances: 1
  resource_pool: common-resource-pool
  networks:
    - name: webapp-network
      static_ips:
        - 52.40.58.163
    - name: default
      default: [dns, gateway]

properties:
  webapp:
    admin: foo@bar.com
    servername: 52.40.58.163
```

Comment: Are you trying to deploy this on Bluemix or AWS? You may need to retag, or clarify in the question.

Comment: I am trying to deploy it to AWS. I've changed tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is coming because there is an missing properties in network configuration. Provides the subnet id and try it. it will work.